# Convert php array to json format?

Tags: php

I have array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => tag 1 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => tag 2 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => tag 3 ) )
```

I need convert it to json:

```
["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3"]
```

How can I do it?

I am trying this:

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

but I have wrong format in result:

```
[{"name":"tag 1"},{"name":"tag 2"},{"name":"tag 3"}]
```

Comment: I'm trying. Look on my post. I am trying this:

echo json_encode($array);
but I have wrong format in result:

[{"name":"tag 1"},{"name":"tag 2"},{"name":"tag 3"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multi-dimensional array.  Extract the `name` columns from it into a single dimension first:

```
echo json_encode(array_column($array, 'name'));
```

Or for PHP < 5.5.0:

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function($v) { return $v['name']; }, $array));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this ways-

Simple `foreach()`

```
<?php
$array=array ( array ('name' => 'tag 1' ),array ( 'name' => 'tag 2'),array('name' => 'tag 3' )
            );
$result = [];            
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
    $result[] = $value['name'];
}            

echo json_encode($result);
```

**DEMO**: https://3v4l.org/siG6Y

Cool way to do that using `array_map()`

```
$result = array_map('current', $array); 
echo json_encode($result);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/qmkUQ

Using `array_column()` if **(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0, PHP 7)**

```
$result = array_column($array,'name');     
echo json_encode($result);
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/7iJ80